# table inside a div stretches the div horizontally more than 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]A table has large number of columns (30 columns) and each of the `th` tags have `white-space:nowrap` style set on them. This stretches the parent div. How can this be prevented and have a horizontal scroll for the div. ?

```
<style>
    .monthly_rental_payment_daily th {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .monthly_rental_payment_daily td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
        <div style="width: 100%;" class="dashboardBox" id="dashboard-monthly-rental-payment">

        <div class="dashboardBoxTitle" id="dashboard-monthly-rental-payment-title">
            <span>Monthly Rental Payments</span>
        </div>
        <div style="height:auto" class="dashboardBoxBody"
             id="dashboard-monthly-rental-payment-body">

        <table
                class="monthly_rental_payment_daily tablesorter standardTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left;padding-right: 15px">Location</th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">Total to be paid</th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">Total paid to date</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">Total still to be paid</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>


            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">1st - 7th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">8th-14th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">15th-21st</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">22nd+</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>



            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">1st - 7th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">8th-14th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">15th-21st</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">22nd+</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>


            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">1st - 7th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">8th-14th</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">15th-21st</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

            <th class="left" style="padding-right: 15px">22nd+</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 15px"></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, I've found out that all of this is inside a div which is inside a td of a tr. If brought out of the tr, the scroll bar appears as it should. When inside the tr, this simply stretches the tr irrespective of whether you use 50% or 100% for the div width. The width percentage only reduces the width of the div but not of the outer tr if that makes sense.

Comment: the different versions can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/5/

Comment: the http://jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/3/ seems to answer your question "How can this be prevented and have a horizontal scroll for the div?"

Comment: @TMS - The outer table will always be present as in  jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/5. jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/3 was an example to show that without the outer table it works normally as it should but with table it doesn't. So, the question is how to make it work even when the outer table is present ?

Comment: i have given my answer. check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. First of all i am going to take your latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rkpolepeddi/d4nc2/5/.

The problem is that table not taking actual width of column, it is taking the content of the columns. So we need to force don't stretch the table based on the table column content.

We have one option here. That is `table-layout` CSS property. What `table-layout:fixed` property will do? Look at the following definition.

```
The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells
```

So simple. Add the `table-layout:fixed` to your outer cell like below.

```
.outer_table {
   width:100%;    
   table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4nc2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing your code, I can only guess. try to set a width on the div and set overflow-x to scroll.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to comment and ask to see the code, than post a guess?

Comment: I've posted the code now. This div is inside a Jquery tab. (The reason I mention this is Jquery tab is another outer div).

Answer (score 1):

Use the style `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` in your div.  In the div containing the table, also try setting the max width to 100% as well like this: `max-width: 100%`

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95Xy6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto` in your div [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/95Xy6/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x:scroll`. it will provide a scroll effect.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AuX2Z/1/)

Comment: I've tried the overflows and stuff. Nothing seems to stop it from stretching.

Comment: you have given width 100% to parent div. so it will scroll when table has more data. if you reduce width of it, it will show more scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/AuX2Z/2/

Comment: The requirement is that the scrollbar should appear before the page width is exceeded.